# Flutter: How to implement Dropdown List to Display Textfield on Click?

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-emulator

I'm relatively new to Flutter and I'm trying to achieve a functionality where upon selecting an item from a dropdown list, a TextField widget appears below it.

Here's the code snippet for my DropdownButton:

```
final items = ['Healthy', 'Unhealthy'];
 ...

    DropdownMenuItem<String> buildMenuItem(String item) => DropdownMenuItem(
          value: item,
          child: Text(
            item,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontFamily: "Ubuntu",
              color: Colors.black54,
            ),
          ),
        );

     ...

      Container(
        width: scrwidth * 0.8,
        height: scrheight / 14,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 12, vertical: 4),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black54, width: 1),
        ),
        child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton<String>(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.arrow_drop_down,
              color: Colors.black54,
            ),
            hint: const Text(
              "Health",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "Ubuntu",
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            isExpanded: true,
            value: value,
            items: items.map(buildMenuItem).toList(),
            onChanged: (value) =>
                setState(() => this.value = value),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Currently, the TextField widget is not displayed. Here's how it looks now:

[image]

I've searched online for solutions, but haven't found anything that addresses my specific issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a visibility widget to show/hide a textfield.  This will be controlled by a state variable, which we will call isVisible.  So we have

```
bool isVisible = false;

.....

Visibility(
    visible: isVisible,
    child: TextField(),
);
```

By default, the textfield won't be shown, but we can make it visible when a dropdown list value is selected.

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
    ....
onChanged: (value) =>
          setState(() {
              this.value = value;
              if (this.value == "Unhealthy") {
                  isVisible = true;
               } else {
                  isVisible = false;
                      }
                })
           );
```